# How do I get past the overseers in High Oversser Campbell without being seen?

Tags: dishonored

I’m having some real trouble with the first assassination. I’m where I saved the guy from the first overseer. I can’t get past the other 5 on the other side of the gate without confronting them. I tried to kill the one walking into the bunker, but then there was another one.

Any advice on how I can proceed?

Comment: Its been a while since i played but i'm quite sure there is a fence (i believe on the left of where your freed the other bloke) with barbed bars on top, you should be able to blink over there. There should also be a window close to there that lets you into a basement of sorts, thus bypassing the guards.

Comment: In most cases with Dishonored; there is always an alternative route. Keep an eye out for out of sight perches, ledges or poorly guarded alleys.

Comment: Are you talking about the part where you're trying to get to the meeting chamber?

Answer (score 2):

By my estimation, you've just saved Overseer Martin, and are here, at this gate:

[image]

I like to Blink up to the air duct next to the gate. You have to jump and blink at the same time:

[image]

From there, you overlook an open area with three overseers. My preferred strategy is to Blink onto the tops of the street lights:

[image]
[image]

Blinking onto the next couple of lights gets you close enough to Blink to the stone ledge:

[image]

and from there across to the ledge of the building High Overseer Campbell is in:

[image]

You now overlook the main courtyard of the Overseer's building. Staying on this ledge will lead you to an open window where you can enter without confronting any enemies.

[image]
[image]

Ta-Da! You're in! Now to navigate the interior of the building.

Even if you haven't spent runes on upgrading Blink, I think this method will still work. Blink is probably the best skill Corvo has since it allows you to take so many new paths.